# Sync Android database with a server database

Tags: php, android, mysql, database, synchronization

I have an Android app with two databases. I need to sync them with two identical (same fields structure and fields name) databases on a web server. But first I need to look into another database on a webserver, pull some information from it and than sync those two databases with some additional data from the first database. Ive been working on the Android app for some time now and I just learned enough PHP with MySQL to build a web application with basic CRUD.

I have a couple of questions:

- How do I sync those databases in Android?
- Can the synchronisation work both ways? If I change database data in Android, can I change them accordingly on web server and vice versa?

Im working on a basic GUI for older people so that they can use an Android phone. My web application should add contacts and reminders into databases in Android application, but when I add contact or reminder manualy in my Android application, I want to see those in my web application as well (both way sync).

Thank you! :)

Comment: You've got great pointers listed below. Please note though that you don't necessarily need to have a database on the android device. Why keep one on the device and one on the server? Instead, just have the database on the server and communicate with it using the methods shown by others. Android devices are typically connected to the internet so you can save yourself the hassle of synchronizing the databases.

Answer (score 2):

I think what you basically want to do is create an API to bridge the data on devices and the data on your server.

This [site](http://www.gen-x-design.com/archives/create-a-rest-api-with-php/) helped me a lot when creating a basic API from scratch. You'll have to understand the basics of how GET and POST work, but once you get that the process of making an API for simple data transfering is pretty straight forward.

If you really want to streamline the process of creating a database with an API I would recommend checking out a service called [StackMob](http://stackmob.com/). That service allows you to set up some pretty simple (and complex) tables and it generates APIs to help you connect those tables to HTML5, iOS, and Android.

Answer (score 2):

I will share how synchronize data between Android application and PHP server USING PHP files , it's more easy than web service etc.. and it's give the same result with the same return.

**Querying**

*** -> PHP side :***

- Create your Table Structure for example : MyTableName : columns Login / Password
- Create a PHP file to query data from your table name

  ```
  <?php
  //To Connect to your Data base
    mysql_connect("localhost","root","");
    mysql_select_db("YourDataBaseName");
  // To execute a query from Your table

    $sql=mysql_query("SELECT *  FROM `Your_Table_Name");

    while($row=mysql_fetch_assoc($sql))
    $output[]=$row;

   // Convert to Json format 
   print(json_encode($output));
   // mysql_close();
  ?>
  ```
- Name your PHP file as your table Name for example : MyTableName.php
- Put this file in your root server directory : for example in Wamp server the www directory
- Test the return data using a browser, using your URL like 
  [www.localhost/MyTableName.php](http://www.localhost/MyTableName.php), normally you will have all your query
  content in Json format.

*** -> Android side :***

- Download this class 'ClientHTTP' https://www.dropbox.com/s/odpaus1tjhd9orv/ClientHTTP.java
- Add Internet Permission in your manifest.
- Inside the click of your button Synchronize put :

  ```
  String lReturn=_myClientHtpp.readFromUrl(www.localhost/MyTableName.php);
  // It will return a json format (Like navigator)
  //Code to Clear your data from Sqlite data base  TABLE ....

   try {
   // Create your Json Array
   JSONArray lList=new JSONArray(lReturn);
   // Iterate the json arry to get each Json object
   for (int i = 0; i < lList.length(); i++) {

  JSONObject lObject=lList.getJSONObject(i);

  String lLogin=lObject.getString("Login");
  String lPWD=lObject.getString("PassWord");

  //Code to Insert in Sqlite data base .....
  }
  } catch (JSONException e) {
   e.printStackTrace();
  }
  ```

**updating**

*** -> PHP side :***

```
<?php
//Connect to Database
  mysql_connect("localhost","root","");
  mysql_select_db("YourDataBase");


 $sql= mysql_query("INSERT INTO YourTableName (Login,PassWord) VALUES ('".$_REQUEST['PARAM_Login']."','".$_REQUEST['PARAM_PWD']."')");

 if($sql==1){
 echo "true";
 }else{
 echo "false";
 }

// mysql_close();
?>
```

- Put this PHP file in your main server directory www, and name it to
  Insert.php
- Test your Insert using browser with this URL [www.localhost/insert.php?PARAM_LOGIN=test&PARAM_PWD=test](http://www.localhost/innsert.php?PARAM_LOGIN=test&PARAM_PWD=test)
- Typically  you will get 'True' and in your server table name a new
  row with test / test will be added.

*** -> Android side :***

- Inside the click of your 'Add' button write :

  ```
      // List of params
  ArrayList<NameValuePair> lListOfParams=new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();

  // Param login
  BasicNameValuePair PARAM_Login=new BasicNameValuePair("PARAM_Login", "test from Android");
  // Param PWD
  BasicNameValuePair PARAM_PWd=new BasicNameValuePair("PARAM_PWD", "Test from Android");

  // Add params to List
  lListParams.add(PARAM_Login);
  lListParams.add(PARAM_PWd);

  // Execute the post method from your ClientHttp class
  boolean lIsInsert=_myClientHtpp.SendToUrl("www.localhost/insert.php", lListOfParams);

  if(lIsInsert)
      Toast.makeText(this, "Insert Success", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
  else
      Toast.makeText(this, "Insert Error", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
  ```
- If your have your own server replace localhost per your domain name.
- If you are using emulator , replace your localhost domaine name per
  your actual IP address for example the query URL becomes :
    192.168.1.2/MyTableName.php

Answer (score 0):

You need a WebService so you can communicate with the DataBase Server & the Android Device.

Develop a Web Service: It should have the logic to fetch data from the Database-Server & Back to Database-Server.

On Android side you can use KSoap to consume the web service. [See this example here.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3730312/how-to-call-a-php-webservice-from-android-using-ksoap2)

Comment: So I develop a WebService on the Android side, that can send data to server and fetch them from server too? Do I have to do anything on the server side?

Answer (score 0):

You need to develop web services to achieve synchronization. I have used SOAP protocol to establish communication between android application and asp.net application. Basically we have developed game application which have admin panel and server database in asp.net and sql server 2008 and android application has SQLite database. These both databases are synchronized through web services. You can also use restful web services instead of SOAP