# Mobile application: exchange data between SQLite and SQL Server 2008

Tags: android, sql-server-2008, sqlite

I'm asked to create a mobile application that loads regulary data from an sql server 2008 and puts it in the local db SQLite and sends it as well. Being a newbie in mobile development i don't even know how to procede. I would be gratefull if anyone leads me or gives me tips. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

You need a WebService so you can communicate with the DataBase Server & the Android Device.

Develop a Web Service: It should have the logic to fetch data from the Database-Server & Back to Database-Server.

On Android side you can use KSoap to consume the web service. [See this example here.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3730312/how-to-call-a-php-webservice-from-android-using-ksoap2)